# Prevent URL encoding of custom query parameters passed to FormState::setRedirectUrl()

Tags: 8, forms, uri

Upon submission of a custom-coded form, I'm redirecting to a URL that includes query parameters. How can I prevent Drupal from URL-encoding those parameters?

Example:

```
$params = [
  'something' => '1,2,3',
  'something_else' => '4,5,6',
];
$url = Url::fromRoute('<current>', $params);
$form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
```

Results in the URL below:

```
http://example.com/page?something=1%2C2%2C3&something_else=4%2C5%2C6
```

But I'd like:

```
http://example.com/page?something=1,2,3&something_else=4,5,6
```

Comment: I have a similar problem where a Drupal 8 redirect from `/placeholder` to `https://proxydomain.com/page?uri=http://example.com`  gets encoded into `https://proxydomain.com/page?uri=http%3A//example.com`. The EZproxy doesn't handle the `%3A` well and it appears to be challenging to fix on their side, so I'm looking for a Drupal fix to not encode `:`  as `%3A`. RFC 3986 claims "one frequently used [query parameter] value is a reference to another URI, it is sometimes better for usability to avoid percent-encoding those characters." :'( Thanks Drupal.